# How do I sum and group values in Array of Hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following data structure:

```
a = [
  { "payer": "UNILEVER", "points": 200, "timestamp": "2020-10-31T11:00:00Z" },
  { "payer": "DANNON", "points": -200, "timestamp": "2020-10-31T15:00:00Z" },
  { "payer": "MILLER COORS", "points": 10000, "timestamp": "2020-11-01T14:00:00Z" },
  { "payer": "DANNON", "points": 300, "timestamp": "2020-10-31T10:00:00Z" }
]
```

I want to sum up all `point` by `payer`. How can I do so?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is the input an array? What do you expect as the output?

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what your question is. :) The answer to the title is `a[0]["payer"]` for example, but don't think that is what you are looking for. Do you want to add up the points by payer or is that a question?

Comment: I adjusted your question and hope I made the intent clear. If that is not what you wanted to ask, please rewrite it as you please.

Answer (score 2):

```
a.group_by {|h| h[:payer] }
 .transform_values {|a| a.sum {|h| h[:points] } }

# => {"UNILEVER"=>200, "DANNON"=>100, "MILLER COORS"=>10000}
```

Comment: @demir solution is likely more efficient but this is a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.group_by { |element| element[:payer] }.each_with_object({}) { |(payer, records), result| result[payer] = records.inject(0) { |sum, record| sum + record[:points]  } }
=> {"UNILEVER"=>200, "DANNON"=>100, "MILLER COORS"=>10000}
```

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
a = [{ "payer": "UNILEVER", "points": 200, "timestamp": "2020-10-31T11:00:00Z" },
     { "payer": "DANNON", "points": -200, "timestamp": "2020-10-31T15:00:00Z" },
     { "payer": "MILLER COORS", "points": 10000, "timestamp": "2020-11-01T14:00:00Z" },
     { "payer": "DANNON", "points": 300, "timestamp": "2020-10-31T10:00:00Z" }]
```

Code

```
result=a.group_by { |h| h[:payer] }.values.map do |arr|
  arr.reduce do |h1, h2|
    h1.merge(h2) do |k, f, s|
      k.eql?(:points) ? f + s : f
    end
  end
end
p result
```

Output

```
#=>[{:payer=>"UNILEVER", :points=>200, :timestamp=>"2020-10-31T11:00:00Z"}, {:payer=>"DANNON", :points=>100, :timestamp=>"2020-10-31T15:00:00Z"}, {:payer=>"MILLER COORS", :points=>10000, :timestamp=>"2020-11-01T14:00:00Z"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get result with single loop:

```
a.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }) { |o, r| r[o[:payer]] += o[:points] }
# => {"UNILEVER"=>200, "DANNON"=>100, "MILLER COORS"=>10000}
```